# If $S$ is open and $S = A \cup B$ where $\overline{A} \cap B = A \cap \overline{B} = \emptyset$, then $A$ and $B$ are open.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I have to prove that

If $S$ is open and $S = A \cup B$ where $\overline{A} \cap B = A \cap \overline{B} = \emptyset$, then $A$ and $B$ are open.

Any ideas?

Comment: Note that $\bar{A}^c$ is open and contains $B$. Hence $S \cap \bar{A}^c = B$.

Comment: Is $\bar{A}^c= A$ that is the complement of the complement?

Comment: No, that would be pointless. It is the complement of the closure. I presume the overbar means closure above.

Comment: Ah sorry for the notation. The bar means complement or at least it does in my book.

Comment: The notation  $\bar{A}$ is often used to denote the to mean the closure of set $A$, and sometimes to denote the complement of set $A$.  Which is it in this problem?  If it is the former, then I think the statement is untrue.  If the latter, then it appears that one of  $A$ or $B$ must be $S$, and the other one $\emptyset$, in which caste the proof is tirival, $S$ being open.

Comment: The bar means complement in my book.

Comment: If it  means complement, then the statement is false. Take $A=(-1,0) \cup (0,1)$, and $B=\{0\}$.

Comment: Using bar in the context of real analysis typically means closure. What text book are you using?

Comment: Yes you are right. I just misunderstood something. We are using real analysis by William Trench.

Comment: I think he uses $\ ^c$ for complement, so I imagine the above is closure.

Answer (score 0):

S=U{B(s)|s is in S} where each B is open =U{B(s)| s is in A} U U{B(s)|s is in B}. But since this is just A U B, A and B are open.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose one of $A$ or $B$ is not open. Without loss of generality, say $A$. Then there is an $x \in A$ such that for all $\epsilon >0$, $B_\epsilon(x) \cap S \setminus A \neq \emptyset$. But $S \setminus A = B$, so this says that $x$ is a limit point of $B$. But by assumption, $\overline{B} \cap A = \emptyset$.